Disable TLSv1.3 in apache2
I would like to disable the use of TLSv1.3 in apache2 and only use TLSv1.2
I tried a few changes in the ssl.conf file, like:

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLProtocol all -TLSv1.3
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.3

and did some tests with the openssl s_client, all with the same result. The server keeps accepting TLSv1.3 and TLSv1.2 requests.
I don't understand what is going wrong or what I should configure.

Why would you want to do that?

You'd have to present a very strong reason to do so. If some other part of the system is ancient as hell so it chokes on TLSv1.3, upgrade that instead.

A couple of possible reasons came in mind.

Did you reload the configuration or restart Apache? (sudo systemctl reload apache2)

Is the configuration really read from the ssl.conf?

Does the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf have IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf?
Is the ssl.conf symlinked to conf-enabled/ssl.conf or just in conf-available/? (On systems with that configuration structure, sudo a2enconf ssl should enable it.)


Is the SSLProtocol overridden? The ssl.conf configures it globally in the server config context, but it could have been overriden in the virtual host context. You could search for all the occurences of the directive with, e.g.,
grep "SSLProtocol" -rs /etc/apache2/



